# C#, C++/cli: How do you unit test a component that can only be loaded once per process

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jvm

I'm currently implementing a .NET wrapper for a Java library by using JNI to start the JavaVM and interacting with Java classes. To be on the save side, I'd like to have unit tests for my code.

The Problem I'm facing now is, you only can start the Java VM once per process. There is no possibility to unload the JVM.

This makes it rather difficult to write unit tests that are actually clean.

Some specs:
.NET/Java interface: done in C++/cli
Unit testing lib: NUnit
Unit testing code: C#

Any tips?

Regards,
Dominik

Comment: loading the JVM Using JNI into a C++/CLI project.  Either your bored or working on something very very interesting....

Comment: @Spence: I'd say interesting! :) It's actually a wrapper for a very small API (5 classes) to an existing Java lib (the lib has > 6000 LOC) we use internally. To rewrite the functionality and to maintain two source trees seemed not really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an ad-hoc .Net test application, that would run on its own process.

Your NUnit tests would thus launch this process (even in command line), let it actually run the tests, and the return the value as std output. IOW, keep it simple and launch many processes.